# R leaflet plot with ETRS89

Tags: coordinate-system, r, leaflet

I am new to GIS and R leaflet, and I am trying to plot the starting points of protected rivers in Spain. Example of coordinates from the original file:

```
Nombre.de.los.cauces.principales Coordenada.X.inicio.cauce..UTM..ETRS.89. Coordenada.Y.inicio.cauce..UTM..ETRS.89.
1 Río Burbia 679349 4742582
2 Río Porcarizas 677311 4737191
3 Río de Tejera 675899 4735382
...
```

The coordinates are in ETRS89, so I am using [EPSG:25828](https://epsg.io/25828) for the plot (the proj4def has been copied directly from the EPSG-page). I defined the CRS as follows:

```
epsg25828 <- leafletCRS(
     crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS", code = "EPSG:25828",
     proj4def = "+proj=utm +zone=28 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
     resolutions = 2^(13:-1), # 8192 down to 0.5
 )
```

This is used in leaflet as follows:

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(csr = epsg25828)) %>%
addTiles() %>% 
addMarkers(lng = 675899, lat = 4735382)
```

The result is a world map with a marker at the top: 
[image: R PLot]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html

```
# Displaying shapes with custom projections

While tiles must be in the same projection as used in the leafletCRS function,
you must always use WGS 84 longitude/latitude data for markers, circles, 
polygons, and lines. Leaflet will automatically project the 
coordinates when displaying.
```

So in your map leaflet is trying to map lat-long of `(lng = 675899, lat = 4735382)` which is invalid since the numbers are greater than 180/90 degrees.

You should only use `leafletCRS` if your **tiles** are in a different coordinate system. The standard OSM ones -- and most others -- are in EPSG:3857 and so that's the default.

If you have point or polygon data in another coordinate system you have to convert them to true lat-long first, which you can do with `st_transform` from the `sf` package or various other ways.

But when I try and convert your points using the EPSG code you give I end up with points in Africa and not Spain. "ETRS89" is not a projected coordinate system, its an earth reference system that projections are based on...

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman. The file with the coordinates does not specify an EPSG coordinate code, but EPSG:3042 ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N (N-E) seems to make sense.